# Coding a loop inside of an Array in pseudocode

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, pseudocode

I'm new to computer science. I've been told there is only 1 bug in the following Java type pseudo-code but i'm unable to figure it out. Isn't there more then 1? First the if statement means it won't loop as size doesn't equal max size, but i think the loop is also incorrect as rather then i<=size shouldn't it be i<=maxsize?

```
private int size = 0;
private int maxsize = 16;
private int[] arr = new int[maxsize];

public void append(val, list)
{
    if (size == maxsize)
    {
        int[] newArr = new int[maxsize * 2];
        for (i = 0; i <= size ; i++)
            newArr[i] = arr[i];
        arr = newArr;
        maxsize = maxsize*2;
    }
    arr[size++] = val;
}
```

Out of these options, which one is correct?

- Line 1 should read: `private int size = 16;`
- Line 7 should read: `if (size > maxsize)`
- Line 10 should read: `for (i = 0 ; i <= maxsize ; i++)`
- Line 13 should come before line 10
- Line 15 should read: `arr[++size] = val;`

Comment: IMHO the `if` condition is correct: `size` is the number of occupied places in the array and `maxsize` is size of the array (the total number of places). As long as `size` is less than `maxsize` you don't need to create a bigger array to store a new value (since there is still room left).

Comment: Also, within the `for` loop it doesn't matter whether you write `i <= size` or `i <= maxsize` because this loop is only executed when `size == maxsize`.

Comment: Out of these options, which one is correct? |Line 1 should read: private int size = 16;|

Line 7 should read: if (size > maxsize)|

Line 10 should read: for (i = 0 ; i <= maxsize ; i++)|

Line 13 should come before line 10|

Line 15 should read: arr[++size] = val;|

Comment: I've edited the code the match the formatting of the original and added your comment to the question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Copying elements from arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69481709/copying-elements-from-arrays)

Answer (score 1):

There’s just an off-by-one error.  The code is trying to copy size+1 elements from the old array into the new, but the old array only has size elements.

Answer (score 0):

There is certainly more than one bug/issue in this code. Here are some I found

- The for loop uses the variable `i` without declaring it
- `size = 0` so the code inside the for loop never actually runs
- `newArr` has all of its elements set equal to the elements in `arr`, and then you go and assign `arr` to `newArr`! This means that the `newArr` variable will point to the same array as the `arr` variable, meaning they are no longer duplicates but rather the exact same piece of data
- Your function takes in `list` but doesn't use it. This is clearly an issue if the function's intention was to append the `val` to `list`
- Your function and maxsize constant should be static unless these are fields inside of an object and intend to be used as such

I've gone ahead and fixed your code: [(Try it here)](http://jdoodle.com/ia/hK8)

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int[] myInts = new int[]{1, 2, 4};
    for(int i = 0; i < myInts.length; i++){
        System.out.print(myInts[i]+ " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
    myInts = append(5, myInts);
    for(int i = 0; i < myInts.length; i++){
        System.out.print(myInts[i]+ " ");
    }
}
private static int maxsize = 16;
public static int[] append(int val, int[] list){
    int size = list.length;
    if(size < maxsize){
        int[] newArr = new int[size+1];
        for (int i = 0; i < size ; i++){
            newArr[i] = list[i];
        }
        newArr[size] = val;
        return newArr;
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: Out of these options, which one is correct? |Line 1 should read: private int size = 16;|

Line 7 should read: if (size > maxsize)|

Line 10 should read: for (i = 0 ; i <= maxsize ; i++)|

Line 13 should come before line 10|

Line 15 should read: arr[++size] = val;|

Comment: Remove line 1, line 7 should read `(size < maxsize)` (don't continue if the array has reached its max size), line 10 should stay the same, except switch the equality operator to `<` (remove the equals), and your code is only 13 lines long so I don't know about the rest...